# Transitive, Intransitive and Potential Verbs

Tags: grammar, verbs, transitivity, potential-form

1. Do all tadoshi verbs have a jidoushi verb to pair with?
2. How do you differentiate volitional and non-volitional form verbs? Do we categorise them like we do for jidoshi (intransitive form) eg. Action performed without an object
3. Are all jidoshi verbs, potential form?

Answer (score -1):

1 not necessarily but for most it's true and if a corresponding verb doesn't exist you can also use the passive verb form to create one (話される事 hanasareru koto the matter which was talked about )

most verbs are 自動 when they use aru like kawaru 変わる and 他動 with eru 変える kaeru however there are also reverse structures like 殖える and 殖やす. Most verbs for beginners follow the first structure but depending on how much you learn per day I would look up each verb to make sure it's the right form

2. Normally at least for godan verbs (every non eru iru ending verb + some exceptions like 切る kiru cut 切ります kirimasu and 帰る kaeru  帰ります  kaerimasu which are also godan) it works like this change the u syllable to e! AND ADD RU! 話す hanasu talk 話せる can talk. For the ichidan use the passive form られる rareru attached to the verb (they're the same. a bit tricky but you'll get used to what is actually meant by context) there are some verbs like 見る which have special forms 見える can be seen which is much more common then using 見られる which is almost only used for the passive.
3. Yes as far as I know at least you can do it by grammar. There might be verbs where it doesn't make sense (none does come to my mind if there are any) but potentially all can be conjugated

Comment: mimiBae's third question is "**Are** all jidoshi verbs potential form?" (emphasis added), but you seem to have answered as if it were "Do all jidoshi verbs **have** potential forms?"